# The usage of the words "saturate" and "saturation"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

I need to know how shall I substitute the verb **saturate** and its respective noun **saturation** in the meaning in my question!

Please consider the following self-made sentences and the bold parts:

> - She **made me saturated of love**! (she was so kind and gave me so much love so that I don't feel any need or greed for getting love from another woman)
> - Now, I am **saturated with** love and all these experiences. Because, I've had enough so far!
> - I have **reached the saturation degree in** stuff like that.

This is how we say these sentences in a polite/formal situation in our language, but according to the dictionaries' explanations, the only possible word to convey this message is "saturation" and subsequently "saturate"!

I have no idea if this word works here properly or if not how should I imply the same messages in natural English?

Comment: It is incorrect to say "saturated **of** love" but "saturated **with** love" in your first example.

Answer (score 3):

"Saturated" and "saturation" are technical words (for chemistry) that aren't often used as metaphors, so expressions like these are possible but unlikely.

As Tasneem ZH said, it's "saturated **with**", not "saturated of", so the first example is wrong and the second is right. Since "saturate" is a transitive verb, the first example could also be "She has saturated me with love!".

"Degree" is not used with "saturation", so the third example should be simply "I have reached saturation with stuff like that." However, it's still an unlikely expression, so it might not be understood. A native speaker would usually say "I've had enough of stuff like that" instead.

Comment: You've mentioned several times that that expression is unlikely to be used to describe such a situation; thus, what would you, as a native speaker, suggest to use instead _for the first and second examples_ (you have suggested an alternative for the third one)? I thought of "fill up", so it would be for #1: "Her love filled me up", and for #2: "I'm filled up with love..."

Comment: "Saturated with love" isn't unnatural English (there's apparently even a song by that name!); it's just not the usual way to say this.

For the first example: "She's filled me up with love", or keeping the metaphor, "She's saturated me with love". For the second, "I'm filled up with love" works, or "I'm overflowing with love".